# Are Functions actually hoisted first before the variables?

Tags: javascript, compilation, hoisting

Someone sent me this pic on Discord saying Functions are hoisted first and then the variables.

prnt .sc/xdwc9a (please delete the space before dot, I dont want to spam)

His statement seems true cause the function is being invoked without throwing any error.

Kyle Simpson also says the same thing in his YDKJS book:

- bit .ly/39Wolka

However, when i experiment with it, I dont get what I expect.
logger() // 10

```
function logger(){

var x = 10;

function x(){

console.log('Function code')

}

function x(){
  console.log("more code")
}

console.log(x)

}
```

This returns 10 however since functions are hoisted first, x function should have been hoisted and in the second run of hoisting (which hoist variables) when it tried to hoist var x; it should've ignored it cus the function x was already hoisted but it doesn't seem like that's what happening here!

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Using the mental picture of hoisting, I'd think about it like this.

Note that if an identifier **a** is used for a function, a subsequent re-declaration **var a** makes no difference. **a** still references that same function.

```
function a(){console.log('hello')}
console.log(typeof a);     //function
var a;
console.log(typeof a);     //function
a();                       //hello
```

Also, if an identifier **a** is used for a function, that identifier can be reassigned to say a number.

```
'use strict';
function a(){}
console.log(typeof a);     //function
a = 123;
console.log(typeof a);     //number
```

Even in strict mode, the declaration of a function seems to then allow the use of that identifier with no preceding **var** or **let**.

Taking your logger code, and moving the nested functions and var x to the top, as per the model of hoisting

```
function logger(){
  function x(){                     //hoisted at compile time
    console.log('Function code')
  }
  function x(){                     //hoisted at compile time
    console.log("more code")
  }
  var x;                            //hoisted at compile time
  //execution time code
  x = 10;
  console.log(x)
}

logger();
```

At the **console.log(x)** line, **x** is the number 10.

Answer (score 0):

Variables get hoisted at first as well as functions. But when variables are hoisted first, their values are `undefined`. On the other hand, function declarations (not expressions or IIFE) get hoisted with their content.

Here is hoisting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting).